# Problems with Windows Task Scheduler (Constantly restarting task)

Tags: windows-7, openvpn, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to configure OpenVPN to automatically start and connect on login. For the most part, my setup works however it starts, goes, and then restarts. This continues forever. Also, the status of the task is perpetually "running."

This is the configuration of the job I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2015-06-24T20:13:08.9260548</Date>
    <Author>JAKE-PC\Jacob</Author>
    <Description>OpenVPN LDN</Description>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <LogonTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <UserId>JAKE-PC\Jacob</UserId>
    </LogonTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>JAKE-PC\Jacob</UserId>
      <LogonType>InteractiveToken</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>false</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>%windir%\System32\cmd.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>/c start "OpenVPN" "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe" --connect LDN-DDoS-Protected.ovpn</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Is there any reason why this is occurring? Also, please let me know if there is any extra information I can provide to facilitate resolving this...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't use Task Scheduler to run program when login, it is too complicated and many settings to go through, my approach is create a .bat file and put it in`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`, let see if you consider this as a alternative solution

Comment: @Bilo Does this run it at highest privileges though? Task scheduler was the only method I could use for that purpose.

Comment: Sorry for my use I always use local admin account, you can try the following way, I think this should work..... create a .bat file to launch the program, `start %1 C:\example.exe`, go to `Task Scheduler`, choose `Create Task...` (NOT `Create Basic Task`), check `Run with highest privileges` and Change the `Configure for:` to  `Windows Server 2003, Windows XP...`, then you can choose the .bat file run at login

Comment: @Bilo Thank you! This worked wonders. I suppose the program blocks, therefore causing the task to stay as "running". Using the batch file to "start" the program, the batch file can finish and exit making the task finish as well. Cool stuff! If you want to post an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Glad to know that is work for you :) However this is just alternative solution , not actually the answer for using Windows Task Scheduler to complete the task, so I put that in comment :)